# Bypass System Validation in Trigger To Update Record

Tags: apex, trigger

I have an object called `objC` which has a `key` field that is a `Text(255) (Unique Case Insensitive)` It's composed of `objA.Id + objB.Id`. Now `ObjC` has a field called `value` wherein it should be updated whenever an `ObjC` record is being created wherein it's `key` value is already existing. Meaning there is already an `ObjC` existing that uses that key.

The issue that I'm facing is that In my trigger, it's not updating the existing `ObjC` record since based on the Apex order of execution it will run System Validation before any record is updated/saved. Is there any way to bypass this issue? Or a better approach for me to check the unique key value wherein it will hinder the insertion of the New ObjC record that uses a key that is existing and it will update the `value` field of the existing `ObjC` record.

Flow in UI

1.) UserA creates objC record with uniqueKey of ObjA.Id+objB.Id. (objC record is created)

2.) UserB creates objC record with uniqueKey of ObjA.Id+objB.Id (Trigger updates userA record's Value field, in the ui of userB it will show an error that uniqueKey is already existing)

Thanks

Comment: Don't understand flow ... but I expect .. using upsert uniquefield__c will solve the problem

Comment: Can you share your existing code in this post?

Comment: is `ObjC` created from the UI or only via code? If the latter, the upsert approach might work per @Ayub.  If the user is creating the record, then your before trigger has to consider uniqueness before setting the `key` field. Please clarify by using [edit]

Comment: Hi, This is all UI except for the updating of exisiting objC which happens in trigger. And guys what do you mean by upsert of uniquefield__c. I'll update my question to make it clearer